# Setting up hMailServer to send and receive email

Tags: email, smtp, settings, imap

I'm trying to configure **hMailServer** on my computer to be able to send email out and also receive emails.  I'm not sure if I have everything set up correctly as some tests works and some others do not so I am confused.

I have already set up in the DNS of my domain these 3 MX records:

```
mail.example.com
smtp.example.com
imap.example.com
```

Each one of those records points to the domain name of my server.  I am able to connect to the web server of my domain.  In my router, I have forwarded ports 25, 110, 143, 465 and 587 to my local computer running the hMailServer application.  When running a port check on the web, it looks like port 25, 110 and 465 are blocked, but the rest are not.

If I open my Mozilla Thunderbird mail client, I set up an account I created in hMailServer for the domain in question.

I have also allowed  the hMailServer  application through my Windows firewall for both the private and public networks.  I did the same for the Thunderbird  email client.

I can locally send emails to myself and other local domains set up in hMailServer.  However, I cannot **send** or **receive** any email to/from **external** recipients, like to/from Gmail or Hotmail for example.  I'm getting this error message:

```
 Error Type: SMTP
   Connection to recipients server failed.
   Error: Host name: 1.1.1.1 (edited) message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Here are the TCP/IP ports summary in hMailServer:

[image]

The second part of my question is once I can actually send and receive email to/from external domains, how would I secure the connection (SSL/TSL...)?  I already have a SSL certificate for my web server (example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).  Do I just need to generate another one for say mail.example.com or do email servers use a different kind of certificate?

Comment: Is Your DNS server local, or is it available to the internet?

Comment: hmm..I did not set up any DNS server....

Comment: If you mean the MX record for the mail server, yes, I have set that up and can ping it.